# Запись результатов двух переменных в txt

Tags: python

Есть две переменные, где хранится результат деления, т.е. дроби с длинными хвостами.
Как можно их сохранить в txt.
Я открываю тхт:

```
file = open('res1.txt', 'a+')
```

Хочу далее записать эти две переменные
далее последовательно добавляю, переменные и пробел между ними

```
file.write(str(var1))
file.write(str(" "))
file.write(str(var2))
```

но теперь я хочу удостовериться, что происходит в том

```
read = open('res1.txt', 'r')
read
```

получаю
`<_io.TextIOWrapper name='res1.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>`

Очевидно, что-то не так.

Вопрос: как я могу занести результат двух переменных и символ между ними, а потом увидеть результат этого сохранения. В идеале, я хотел бы сохранить их округлёнными, без длинных хвостов.

---

не мудрствуя лукаво, я сделал переменную, где как единая строка сволочено всё, что мне надо. или можно рациональнее?

Comment: Пример работы с файлами https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: спасибо. в том описании сказано, что а.) режим аппенд при открытии при дальнейшем записи добавляет что-то:"and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data written to the file is automatically added to the end". открываю при помощи аппенд ````file = open('res1.txt', 'a')```` дальше пытаюсь записать переменную, потом пробел, потом переменную; на выходе имею 18 символов, потом 1, потом 18. т.е. перезапись, а не добавление. а как добавить? ведь если аргументы метода записи через запятую, б. ошибка, что у того метода только 1 аргумент.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> read = open('res1.txt', 'r')
> read
> ```
>
> получаю `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='res1.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>`
>
> Очевидно, что-то не так.

Да, очевидно. Вы только открыли файл, но ничего не прочитали из него, просто вывели объект файла на экран. Чтобы прочитать данные из файла, вызовите например метод `read`:

```
file = open('res1.txt', 'r')
print(file.read())
```

Чтобы выводить данные округленными, используйте, например, f-строки:

```
file.write(f'{var:.3} {var2:.3}')
```

`.3` означает округление до 3 знаков после запятой.